# Need to create a dictionary of two span tags with in a wrapped up in a container. Using beautiful soups

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I am **scraping** some listings of a website and managed to get most of the features to work except **scraping** the description.

here is the URL of one ad : https://eg.hatla2ee.com/en/car/honda/civic/3289785

Here is my code:

```
for link in df['New Carlist Unit 1_link']:
    url = requests.get(link)
    soup  = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')
    ### Get title 
    title =[]
    try:
        title.append(soup.find('h1').text.strip())
    except Exception as e:
        None
    
    
    ## Get price
    price = []
    try:
        price.append(soup.find('span',class_="usedUnitCarPrice").text.strip())
    except Exception as e:
        None

    ##Get Description box
        
    label =[]
    text =[]
    try:
        for span in soup.find_all('span',class_="DescDataSubTit"):
            label.append(span.text.strip())
            text.append(span.find_next_sibling().text.strip())
            
            
    except Exception as e:
        None
    print('*'*100)
    print(title)
    print(price)
    print(label)
    print(text)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I cant seem to collect all the span tags for some reason.

Here is the output I want:

```
{'Make': 'Honda'}
{'Model': 'Crosstour'}
{'Used since': '2012'}
{'Km': '0 Km'}
{'Transmission': 'automatic'}
{'City': 'Cairo'}
{'Color': 'Gold'}
{'Fuel': 'gas'}
```

Comment: Explanations go into your question; there is an [edit] button for that. It is also not clear what "all spans" mean. How do you know there are some missiing?

Comment: check below answer then

Comment: Thanks, mate, I appreciate the "English" lesson.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.select_one("div.DescDataRow").select("span.DescDataSubTit")
    for tar in target:
        g = {tar.text: tar.find_next("span").get_text(strip=True)}
        print(g)


main("https://eg.hatla2ee.com/en/car/honda/civic/3289785")
```

Output:

```
{'Make': 'Honda'}
{'Model': 'Civic'}
{'Used since': '1990'}
{'Km': '1,500 Km'}
{'Transmission': 'automatic'}
{'City': 'Port Said'}
{'Color': 'Dark red'}
{'Fuel': 'gas'}
```

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = [list(item.stripped_strings)
              for item in soup.select("div.DescDataContain")][0][:16]
    print(dict(zip(*[iter(target)]*2)))


main("https://eg.hatla2ee.com/en/car/honda/civic/3289785")
```

Output:

```
{'Make': 'Honda', 'Model': 'Civic', 'Used since': '1990', 'Km': '1,500 Km', 'Transmission': 'automatic', 'City': 'Port Said', 'Color': 'Dark red', 'Fuel': 'gas'}
```